# error prevents upgrade of ubu 18, unable to open /usr/share/perl/5.26.1/warnings.pm.dpkg-new

Tags: apt, upgrade, dpkg, dependencies

`sudo apt upgrade` returns this error:
`libperl5.26 : Depends: perl-modules-5.26 (>= 5.26.1-6ubuntu0.5) but 5.26.1-6ubuntu0.3 is installed`

`sudo apt --fix-broken install` returns this error:
`unable to open '/usr/share/perl/5.26.1/vmsish.pm.dpkg-new': Operation not permitted`

`sudo apt install perl` returns these errors:

````
 libmailtools-perl : Depends: libnet-perl
 libperl5.26 : Depends: perl-modules-5.26 (>= 5.26.1-6ubuntu0.5) but it is not going to be installed
 perl : Depends: perl-modules-5.26 (>= 5.26.1-6ubuntu0.5) but it is not going to be installed```


`sudo apt install perl-modules-526` returns this error:
```unable to open '/usr/share/perl/5.26.1/warnings.pm.dpkg-new': Operation not permitted```
````

Comment: Ubu 18? Please be specific with releases, the error and your pastes imply you're not likely on Ubuntu Core 18 (or another *yy* release of Ubuntu, but more likely a *yy.mm* release; Ubuntu has had *yy* releases since 2016). Please clarify your release as it matters with package conflicts.

Answer (score 2):

The solution was to install libnet-perl before perl-modules-526:

```
sudo apt install libnet-perl
```